# After someone has been invited as a program committee (PC) member on EasyChair, can one change which track they'll review?

Tags: easychair

When inviting someone to the program committee on EasyChair, one can choose which track they'll review:

[image]

After someone has been invited as a program committee (PC) member on EasyChair, can one change which track they'll review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After someone has been invited as a program committee (PC) member on EasyChair, one cannot change which track they'll review, unless one re-invites them again.